# Remove substring from a String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a string containing HTML and a JSON string... I retrieve this string calling an API.
My objective is to retrieve the JSON object from it.

I'm setting 2 variables containing the html beginning and ending and a third empty string.

```
htmlStart = '<html><body><h1>Response</h1><p>The server returned these fields:<p><table border="1"><tr><td>JSONResponse</td><td>';
htmlEnd = '</td></tr></table></body></html>';
response = '';
```

I try to use some regex to remove '\n' and replace to change the final string output.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.apiService.getCategories().subscribe(
    (res) => {
      console.log(typeof res);

      this.response = res
        .replace(/\n/g, '')
        .replace(this.htmlStart, '')
        .replace(this.htmlEnd, '');
      console.log(this.response);
    }
  );
```

It seems that the replace function is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Since the response contains well formed HTML, you can simply treat it as such.

```js
const responseElement = document.createElement('html');
responseElement.innerHTML = this.htmlStart;
const jsonString = responseElement.querySelector('td').textContent;
return JSON.parse(jsonString);
```